# Jquery UI Dialog conditional button text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, conditional-statements, jquery-ui-dialog

What's the correct way to have a UI Dialog "close" button display different text based on a condition?

This was my wild guess which isn't working.

```
$("#settings_popup").dialog({
    buttons: [{
        text: (function() {
            if ("ui-id-1" == curTab) {
                "Save"
            } else {
                "Done"
            }
        }),
        click: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }],
    close: onSettingsClose
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help.  For the main button text, I added return statements to your sample code.

I also added custom hover text for the close button at the top of the window.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var curTab = "ui-id-1";
    $("#settings_popup").dialog({
        buttons: [{
            text: (function() {
                if ("ui-id-1" == curTab) {
                    return "Save";
                } else {
                    return "Done";
                }
            }),
        }],
        closeText: "CloseIt!",
    });
});
```